# Bootstrap columns dynamic

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some problems with the columns. I supposed to have 5 columns for md and larger devices and 4 for sm and 3 for xs. The thing is that in large screens all my columns are on the left part of the screen. I've been going through my code but can't find out why it's been like this.

Right now it is like this:
[image]

Essentially I want it to be like this, and preferably centered within each column (without having words stacked on each other):
[image]

Comment: show us what u tried (code)

Comment: Give me one sec, have to remove the bad parts done by partner :)

Comment: So you having a `row` around the `col-`'s. One `row` has space for 12 `col-`'s. If you want to have 3 `col-`'s in xs you can give each div the class `col-4` because 12 / 3 = 4. Same principle for sm, but you can't divide 12 by 5

Comment: There is no easy way to get 5 centered. full width columns in Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your code is but I would write it like:
Note: you kind of need to do divisions of 12 if you want to the columns to be even. 5 even columns doesn't really work unless you have a offset at either side.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">Blue Box</div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">Blue Box</div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">Blue Box</div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">Blue Box</div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">Blue Box</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope this answers your question, let me know if there is anything further you need me to add or clarify.

Comment: Thing is I'm supposed to hide 1/2 divs for smaller devices

Comment: Oh, and somehow with your code the last div is pushed down, any way I can keep it on the same level?

Comment: you want to hide the divs on smaller devices? That is bad practice, however, if you do then you would need to use media queries. At what size is it pushed down?